# Why is Goldstone boson not observable in the non-Hermitian QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry-breaking

I have recently stumble upon a paper on the spontaneous symmetry breaking of Non-Hermitian QFT [arXiv:1808.00437](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.00437).

On page 8 (at the end of section 3) the author claims that one can not "observe" the goldstone in the non-Hermitian theory (or at least for this specific example).

I'm not sure what the author meant by "observable"? Does that mean one can not find the (free) propagator $<\phi_{\text{gold}}\phi_{\text{gold}}>$ or something?